# Nested layouts get broken, not on their own

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a simple window which I would like to display a button and a label horizontally in a `QHboxLayout` then a `QGroupBox` with some `QRadioButton` displayed vertically in a `QVBoxLayout`. I tried to put these two pieces in a `QVBoxLayout` but with no luck. The result of my code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore


class Application(QtGui.QWidget):
    """ Main application window """

    def __init__(self):
        super(Application, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.openBtn = QtGui.QPushButton("Open", self)
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel("This is a test label", self)

        self.hBox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.hBox.addWidget(self.openBtn)
        self.hBox.addWidget(self.label)

        self.group = QtGui.QGroupBox("Style", self)
        self.radioBtn1 = QtGui.QRadioButton("Button 1", self.group)
        self.radioBtn2 = QtGui.QRadioButton("Button 2", self.group)
        self.radioLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.group)
        self.radioLayout.addWidget(self.radioBtn1)
        self.radioLayout.addWidget(self.radioBtn2)
        self.group.setLayout(self.radioLayout)

        self.hBox2 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.hBox2.addWidget(self.group)

        self.vBox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.vBox.addLayout(self.hBox2)
        self.vBox.addLayout(self.hBox)

        self.setLayout(self.vBox)
        self.show()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainapp = Application()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

is this

[image: Bad result]

I don't get why the `QGroupBox` gets broken. It displays correctly on its own with the following code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore


class Application(QtGui.QWidget):
    """ Main application window """

    def __init__(self):
        super(Application, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
#         self.openBtn = QtGui.QPushButton("Open", self)
#         self.label = QtGui.QLabel("This is a test label", self)
#           
#         self.hBox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
#         self.hBox.addWidget(self.openBtn)
#         self.hBox.addWidget(self.label)

        self.group = QtGui.QGroupBox("Style", self)
        self.radioBtn1 = QtGui.QRadioButton("Button 1", self.group)
        self.radioBtn2 = QtGui.QRadioButton("Button 2", self.group)
        self.radioLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.group)
        self.radioLayout.addWidget(self.radioBtn1)
        self.radioLayout.addWidget(self.radioBtn2)
        self.group.setLayout(self.radioLayout)

        self.hBox2 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.hBox2.addWidget(self.group)

        self.vBox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.vBox.addLayout(self.hBox2)
#         self.vBox.addLayout(self.hBox)

        self.setLayout(self.vBox)
        self.show()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainapp = Application()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

which yields

[image]

I run a Windows 8 64bit machine with Python 3.3 installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're giving `self` as parent to all your layouts. This effectively sets that layout as the main layout for your window (equivalent to `setLayout`). And you do that again...

Basically, you can't set another layout before removing the old one. You should see several warnings in your console.

What happens is, first layout (`self.hBox`) is set as main layout and the rest are ignored. However, your `QGroupBox` has the window as parent. So it's inserted globally (top left). But it has no layout, so it can't adjust its size, and it's shrunk.

If you remove `self` from your layout constructors, you'll get your desired result.

By the way, when using layouts, you can omit the `parent` setting for the widgets/layouts that will go inside the layout. Layouts will set parent-child relationship between the widgets.